# Is !$page == false or $page in php?

Tags: php

I saw the following code which uses if ($page!==false).
What are the differences if I use if ($page)?

```
if($id){ // check that page exists
$page=dbRow("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id=$id");
if($page!==false){
    $page_vars=json_decode($page['vars'],true);
    $edit=true;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also [What does this symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php). It's an explicit value+type check here, for the logic redundant since an empty array and NULL should be treated equivalent.

Comment: in your particular case there is no difference.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, how do you know what `dbRow` returns?  It could plausibly be different if `dbRow` can return an empty array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `$page !== false`, this only checks to see if `$page` is of [boolean type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) (i.e. `true` or `false`) and if it is equal to `false`.  `if ($page)` checks to see if the boolean representation of `$page` is false.  The following values are false when converted to booleans in PHP:

- `null`
- `0` (integer)
- `0.0` (float)
- `''` (empty string)
- `'0'` (string containing the character `0`)
- `array()` (empty array)

So, if `$page` is any of these, `if ($page)` will fail, but `if ($page !== false)` will pass.

Answer (score 2):

The `===` and `!==` compares by value **and** type (strict comparison).

The `==` and `!=` compares by value only (loose comparison).

In your case, the `$page!==false` only evaluates `true` when `$page` is not a boolean with the value `false`.

#### See also:

- [Truth table in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: No, it will also evaluate `TRUE` for *any* non-boolean.

Answer (score 2):

If you use if($page!==false) you are making sure that $page is not false (in this case if $page is 0 or null will not be considered as false as you are forcing type check with !== )

If you use if ($page) it means any thing other than false, 0, NULL, empty string, empty array or any thing that computed as TRUE

Answer (score 1):

There are some falsy things that are `!== false`, such as `NULL`, `0`, `array()`, and the empty string.  The complete list of falsy values is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

`!==` operates by checking that both type and value are identical.  So `$page !== false` will be true unless $page is a *boolean* with the value false.

In contrast `if($page)` will result in the block being executed if `$page` is anything truthy (evaluating to TRUE).  This is basically everything except the values listed in the above link.

Thus, the behavior is different for the falsy values that aren't exactly `false`.