# php difference between !$a and $a === false

Tags: php, booleanquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is !$page == false or $page in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705196/is-page-false-or-page-in-php)

What is the difference between these two types of checks? And which would be the correct way of type checking called functions or methods that fail and return false?

```
if (!is_dir($path)) {...}
```

or

```
if (is_dir($path) === false) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(!is_dir($path)){...}
```

IF is_dir($path) is **EQUAL** to false.

```
(is_dir($path) === false){...}
```

IF is_dir($path) is **IDENTIFCAL** to false. This is more **explicit** in the sense that the result of is_dir($path) MUST be a boolean FALSE value. Nothing else will do.

Run this example:

```
<?php

$var = 0;

if($var == false){
    echo 'Var is EQUAL to FALSE.';
}

if($var === false){
    echo 'Var is IDENTICAL to FALSE.';
}

?>
```

Read up on the comparison operators [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 1):

!$a will be true if $a is set to 0, or if $a is unset. The triple equal sign strictly checks for false, not just for null-ish values.

Answer (score 0):

the `===` operator is the "same value and same type" comparison. So `$foo === false` is only true if `$foo` is already a `bool` type equal to false, whereas `!$foo` will perform different operations depending on the type of `$foo` (for example, if `$foo` is an object or resource, then it will check if it's a null value. If it's a string then it checks for null (and I think an empty string too, but I'm uncertain on that). If it's an integer then it checks if it's zero or not. Basically it works similar to C's `!` operator before they added the bool type (where boolean values were really `int` values).

In your code, both examples are "correct" although the first example, using the `!` operator, is the most succinct and should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to understand by giving some examples(you need to execute php commands in command prompt/ terminal)
! is logical operator not and it is defined by php documentation as "!$a has Result TRUE if $a is not TRUE."

```
php -r "$a=NULL; $b = !$a; var_dump($b);"
```

> returns bool(true)

```
php -r "$a=''; $b = !$a; var_dump($b);"
```

> returns bool(true)

```
php -r "$a=array(); $b = !$a; var_dump($b);"
```

> returns bool(true)

```
php -r "$a=false; $b = !$a; var_dump($b);"
```

> returns bool(true)

```
php -r "$a=0; $b = !$a; var_dump($b);"
```

> returns bool(true)

```
php -r "$a=0.0; $b = !$a; var_dump($b);"
```

> returns bool(true)

`php -r "$a='0'; $b = !$a; var_dump($b);"`

> returns bool(true)

While $a === false will be true only if $a is actuall bollean and its value is false(all other previvious examples will be false with ! operator)

```
php -r "$a=false; $b = $a === false; var_dump($b);"
```

> returns bool(true)

In your example just use not operator ! because you dont need to check type of is_dir result.